# How to search and replace a string deep inside a set of documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Given a collection containing several documents like this one:

```
  {
    sku: 'P001'
    options: [
      {
        name: 'Size',
        value: 'Large'
      },
      {
        name: 'Color',
        value: 'Forest Green'
      },
      {
        name: 'Surface',
        value: 'Rubber'
      }
    ]
  }
```

I want to search for 'Forest Green' and replace it with 'Brilliant Green'. I tried this:

```
Products.update(
  { options: { $elemMatch: { value: 'Forest Green' } } },
  { $set: { 'options.value': 'Brilliant Green' } },
  { multi: true }
)
```

but I get the following error:

> MongoError: cannot use the part (options of options.value) to traverse the element ({options: [ { name: "Size", value: "Large" }, { name: "Color", value: "Forest Green" }, { name: "Surface", value: "Rubber" } ]})

It seems like this should work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should use $ like this

```
{ 'options.$.value': 'Brilliant Green' }
```

The positional $ operator facilitates updates to arrays that contain embedded documents. Use the positional $ operator to access the fields in the embedded documents with the dot notation on the $ operator.
For more info about $ positional operator see this [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation)

```
db.collection.update(
   { <query selector> },
   { <update operator>: { "array.$.field" : value } }
)
```

Thanks

Comment: Worked! Great. Can you modify your answer to explain what this is doing? I don't understand the `options.$.value` syntax.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack, You can check it now. Thanks

Comment: Welcome @CaptSaltyJack. All the best